# Same property type on different levels

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a hook that accepts a type:

```
type TJsonData = {
  message: string;
  activity: string;
};
```

But this type can be on three different levels, so it can accept either:

- `{ message: "", activity: "" }`
- `{ someData: { message: "", activity: "" } }`
- `{ errors: { someError: { message: "", activity: "" } } }`

I managed to make this work without any errors with:

```
type TLoaderData =
  | TJsonData
  | Record<string, TJsonData>
  | {
      errors?: Record<string, TJsonData>;
    };
```

The problem is, inside the hook it can't properly determine the correct type, at least with my current implementation:

```
function useActionNotify(...actions: Array<TLoaderData | undefined>) {
  //...

  useEffect(() => {
    actions.forEach((action) => {
      if (!action) return;

      if (
        action.activity // Error here
      ) {
        return notify(action);
      }

      Object.values(action).forEach((data) => {
        if (data.activity) {
          return notify(data);
        }

        // Data errors will be another object to be looped over
        Object.values(data).forEach((error) => {
          notify(error);
        });
      });
    });
  }, [actions, notify]);
}
```

With the above it gets a type error (or something similar):

```
Property 'activity' does not exist on type 'TLoaderData'.
  Property 'activity' does not exist on type '{ errors?: Record<string, TJsonData> | undefined; }'.ts(2339)
```

How do I make it get the correct type? Is there any other way other than to force typecast, or is my `TLoaderData` wrong to begin with?

Codesandbox for the other errors and full implementation: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-faraday-jxjirf?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [user-defined type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to let TypeScript know which part of your `TLoaderData` type union is handled in each code branch:

```
/**
 * Type predicate
 * https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates
 */
function isJsonData(obj: TLoaderData): obj is TJsonData {
  // Can be implemented using a combination of `in` operator and `typeof` type guards
  return 'activity' in obj && typeof obj.activity === 'string';
}
```

Then you use it in your `if` condition, and TypeScript automatically knows that within the corresponding block, your object is narrowed down to `TJsonData`:

```
if (isJsonData(action)) {
  return notify(action); // Now is okay!
}
```

Just be careful with `Object.values`, which sometimes does not correctly infer the value type. In such case, you can resort to type assertion, or fallback to an old school `for in` loop (but you may still need to type assert the key!):

```
      for (const key in action) {
        const data = action[key as keyof typeof action]

        if (isJsonData(data)) {
          return notify(data); // Okay!
        }

        // Data errors will be another object to be looped over
        Object.values(data).forEach((error) => {
          notify(error); // Still okay!
        });
      }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=42&ssc=8&pln=31&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMCiAzb6DG8AvnNlBCHAERToCGhVA3AFCiSzUB0A9KjAE8ANulRd8qVMxYtBYdHAAqAKVQQAdgBE6MOnAC8iFnDghRqOgHN0ALjj8owdZdYmGMYADdgguw6cuLESssgLySgAyEHQAJuhQ2roGxnAAPkqqGol0KekASgTQMQA8-s4ANBlqWjp0AHy5RibNcPHkUKh2BfhFpTCOFVVZtXWuzcEy2MjqhMAaKBgAchAe2MD4OnPqABQAlE1wtDDIUOqIcOorwNgCdtsxtXYq1dn7+nWIJBNEk9Oz82h0ABBf7qZarATbLjQ9xbTpwIFQKB0ATFRRRWLxbJpFDqOJrdToGJ1fYIFI9dT8c6XCFwEiGQHg67rTYaPYhEyAnB4QjbPYGD5klqwjRibDQTAMAAWfJF6jegpSLWucG2AEI5fsjid1ByWnAVdtgKhMjVdNtNaSlfrtacLlcbhbQbsmHAeDw4MsAO4G1BwCAAaxRautJh+odI0FVFKpAfQAgNZ01B31cBj8AeSUMcoA2nGE3Q-fmINg4HJ0CW4HKALoyVMmQ3G03Ze61XZW+vNW1nGnXSGZugut0egDyQYEIc74c77rg2La0D9XuAQiEcAARgo6DSpfF-euAFYEeAwCAbhRCCAQeQxf2eeIRkwjw-HrieOhCZCiVu6XZccVQJK+AytsC5QAqKb1r2jpgUOs4AMoeKu-rjpO9ZEC6EY-C0GFjEQlQ5nKqCVNBAjVph4Y8AAVFRxhUUoYQKGAtAxCyMDoHRcBSjAMBgJ07peoJXDlqg+COGAMBCNulhcNAlg8DEEASDwUrbjE65XgGPAAEw8OodBIhAy7OFw3EgEIADEaABAAtOWNnMUSbGiHRPAsFMMwePMTYvLU2wQIeTwYnECRtnYAUHr6QxmnoQrDnAACS4AiGY6jsbe1nOFWaYUOuTismclYAAZOEV-ryMip5QFWeJwEV5YlmV5ZwJYyAGTEqApN2cAAOSwt4gg9Ym+6RQAZKNZaMZWEVcP1PgJvoi29WUlg9awRBAA)

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been bugging me for literally days. I didn't know I need to handle it myself, my code worked even with the error anyway so I was stumped why TS was complaining. This is my first time handling unions so I had no idea where or what to search for. Thanks for pointing me to the appropriate docs too.

Comment: Yw, thank you for your nice feedback!